# SAML based Identity provider service on Cloud

Tags: cloud, single-sign-on, ibm-cloud, saml

I am using Bluemix SSO service as service provider. I just want to try establishing an SSO connection from this bluemix service instance to a SAML based identity provider on cloud. This is essential because, this service being a black box, I want to test that it works and understand any of its constraint. My client still has few days before having IDP service available at his end.

Would you know any IDP service on Cloud which is free to try? Appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

There is a free, open-to-use SAML2 idp for development use at http://stubidp.kentor.se.

*For the record: I'm one of the devs behind it*

Comment: That's cool. Thanks Anders! Initial comment ... minor issue in Metadata file, XML declaration is missing, hence got an Invalid XML while uploading to SP. Apart from that I will try out integration today. Do you also have a tool to debug the integration (i.e http proxy which shows what's happening).

Comment: I don't think an xml declaration is needed, haven't seen it required before. If you have a reference that it should be there, please file an issue on [github](github.com/KentorIT/authservices). To see what's happening you can use saml tracer for firefox or the SAML DevTools extension for Chrome.

Comment: Thanks Anders! Yeah probably behaviour specific to Bluemix SSO service. I will log the issue with details to reproduce, just for reference. Currently IDP signs request using self signed private certificate. Is there an option to have requests sign using public certificate, if you have one?